# Migrating Mysql database to Mssql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) to migrate MySQL database to Mssql database. I have successfully connected to MySql database server. **But when i tried to connected with MSSQL database server Connect option is not getting enabled(See below pic).**  MSSql server is installed on same machine and i am able to start MSSQL Database by the same parameters which i am providing into SSMA.

**EDIT--Server Name dropdown did not show any server name. I copied the server name from MSSQL Management studio and put there.**

[image]

Comment: Choose a database and a port maybe?

Comment: As I get a lot of problems migrating databases with this method in the past, I ended up generating the database script (remember to save Schema and Data) and running it in the desired database. Just to point as an alternative.

Comment: There is nothing in database drop down to select.

Comment: Then the tool cannot connect to your server. Troubleshoot connection issues first then come back.

Comment: Why It is not showing local connection in server name. I searched a lot but did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized, that this is a SQLEXPRESS installation, which means the `sa` account is disabled by default.

You were able to choose the sysadmin accounts during installation, use that account using Windows Authentication to connect to the database engine (both is SSMS and SSMA).

If you did not choose any accounts, you may want to search for a way to enable an account and grans sysadmin privileges.

It is also possible, that you'll have to run SSMS or SSMA as administrator (right click on the icon, Run as Administrator).

Please note that using a sysadmin account for day-to-day tasks is not recommended and not secure. I would suggest to create an account for each users and/or applications (or application modules).

Comment: No Success, Windows Authentication didn't help. Server name combo box  not showing any instant. Why? My sql server  is local server.

Comment: SQL Server Browser service is not running, SQL Server instance setup is not correct, firewall problem. This is what I can think of now. Anyways, using the hostname or named pipe should work. Since we know nothing about your installation and there are lots of configurations options in SQL Server the original (connectivity) problem is hard to solve. You may want to try it on [dba.se] or ask a moderator to merge this question to there